# sequelize sum field while still getting objects

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a table that looks like this

```
var competence_develop_comp = sequelize.define('competence_develop_comp', {
            competence_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            level_difference: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            division_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            timestamp : DataTypes.DATE
        }, {
            freezeTableName: true,
            instanceMethods: {
                retrieveByDivision: function (adminDivisions, onSuccess, onError) {
                    competence_develop_comp.sum('level_difference',{
                        include: [{model: Competence}],
                        where: {division_id: {$in: adminDivisions}},
                        order: 'timestamp DESC,level_difference DESC',
                        GROUP: 'competence_id',
                        limit: 10
                    }).ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
                },
                retrieveByDivisionId: function (division_id, onSuccess, onError) {
                    competence_develop_comp.findAll({
                        include: [{model: Competence}],
                        where: {division_id: division_id},
                        order: 'timestamp DESC,     level_difference DESC',
                        limit: 10
                    }).ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

as you can see ive attempted to `sum` the field `level_difference` using the following:

```
competence_develop_comp.sum('level_difference',{
                        include: [{model: Competence}],
                        where: {division_id: {$in: adminDivisions}},
                        order: 'timestamp DESC,level_difference DESC',
                        GROUP: 'competence_id',
                        limit: 10
                    }).ok(onSuccess).error(onError);
```

However when ever i do this i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'map' of undefined
```

The thing is for each result i need a sum of the `level_difference`

So how would i do this using `sequelize`

Comment: What is in onSuccess?

Comment: @YuriZarubin its a callback function